# ENOENT: no such file or directory, error in file directory on entry command

Tags: node.js, parcel

```
> zolo@1.0.0 start
> parcel index.html

Server running at http://localhost:1234 
×  C:\Users\luvri\OneDrive\Desktop\Project - Zolo\Zolo\1x: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\luvri\OneDrive\Desktop\Project - Zolo\Zolo\1x'

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\luvri\OneDrive\Desktop\Project - Zolo\Zolo\1x'
```

Im constantly facing this issue no matter what i try. Everything rounds up back to this same line while building my website on parcel development server.

The directory for my file is only till zolo folder and I have no idea where that 1x is coming from

Can someone help me with this i have almost tried every possible approach i could find